# Неправильно сортируется

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

В каждой строчке таблицы есть: id, название организации, имя капитана команды, город, сумма правильных ответов и статус каждого ответа(правльно/неправильно).
Нужно отсортировать таблицу по сумме правильных ответов, в порядке убывания. Т.е чем больше правильных, тем выше находится запись, но сейчас они находятся в совершенно другом порядке.

Сейчас сортировка осуществляется так:

```
<% @teams.sort_by {|team| team.top(@answers.where(:token => team.token).where("number <= " + @turnir.show.to_s).where("number <= " + locals[:show].to_s).where(:right => true).map(&:number).uniq.count) }.reverse.each_with_index do |team, i| %>
```

Где @teams - список команд. @answers - ответы.

Мы отображаем только те ответы, которые разрешил показывать администратор:

```
 where("number <= " + @turnir.show.to_s).where("number <= " + locals[:show].to_s)
```

Полный код таблицы:

```
<% @teams.sort_by {|team| team.top(@answers.where(:token => team.token).where("number <= " + @turnir.show.to_s).where("number <= " + locals[:show].to_s).where(:right => true).map(&:number).uniq.count) }.reverse.each_with_index do |team, i| %>

    <% @thitteamanswers = @answers.where(:token => team.token).where("number <= " + @turnir.show.to_s).where("number <= " + locals[:show].to_s)%>
    <% @members = Member.where(:token => team.token) %>
    <% @authuser = User.find(Token.find(team.token).user_id) %>

  <tr>
    <th><%= i+1 %></th>
    <td>
      <%= @authuser.organisation %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= 
        if @members.where(:membership => 'captain').first != nil

          @members.where(:membership => 'captain').first.name_fst + ' ' + @members.where(:membership => 'captain').first.family 
        end
      %>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <%= @authuser.city %>
    </td>
    <th>
      <% case @turnir.game_type %>
        <% when "single" %>
          <%= @thitteamanswers.where(:right => true).map(&:number).uniq.count %>
        <% when "race" %>
          <%= @thitteamanswers.sum(:resulttime) %>
      <% end %>
    </th>

    <% (1..@tit).each do |an| %>

      <td>
        <% if an <= @turnir.show && an <= locals[:show].to_i%>
          <% @result = @thitteamanswers.where(:number => an).first %>
          <% case @turnir.game_type %>
            <% when "single" %>
              <%= '1' if @result && @result.right == true %>
              <%= '0' if @result && @result.right == false %>
              <%= '?' if @result && @result.right == nil %>
            <% when "race" %>
              <%= @result.resulttime if @result != nil %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </td>

    <% end %>

    <% if current_user && current_user.is_admin %>
      <th>
        <a href="/edit/<%= @turnir.numbertur %>/<%= team.token %>">Ред </a> &nbsp;
      </th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: Ваш код не соответствует принципам [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) [принятым](http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails) в Rails. Пожалуйста постарайтесь вынести весь код взаимодействия с базой(.where, .find и т.д.) в контроллер или еще лучше в модели.

Comment: или ещё лучше в службы

Comment: сделайте денормализацию (добавьте поле-счетчик) и сортируйте по-человечески, ваш пример ужасен )

Comment: >> вынести весь код взаимодействия с базой(.where, .find и т.д.) в контроллер << плохой совет. пользуйтесь scope